# How to trigger a javascript function when "Processing Math" in MathJax reaches 100%

Tags: javascript, printing, callback, mathjax

I would like to call a javascript `Print()` function when the js library [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) finishes to process the visited web page.

At the moment the `Print()` function is triggered using `onload` but it seems to stop the Processing Math task of MathJax (demo [here](http://1d.latest.stackprinter.appspot.com/export?question=3405&format=HTML&service=math.stackexchange&linktohome=false)); users need to dismiss the browser's Print pop-up to lets MathJax finishes its processing.

I would like to be able to call `Print()` just when Processing Math in MathJax reaches 100%.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Push the Print command onto the MathJax processing queue so that it will be called after MathJax finishes typesetting the page.  E.g.,

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(Print);
```

or

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(function () {
  // do stuff here
  Print();
});
```

See the documentation at

http://www.mathjax.org/resources/docs/?queues.html#the-mathjax-processing-queue

for more details.

Comment: @Davide almost :), it works but when the printer dialog pops-up the Processing Math: 100% does not disappear. Do you know any way to get rid of it?

Comment: Make sure you take OUT the onload hander for the body, which also calls Print.  It is being triggered before MathJax is loaded (and before the Print that is queued via MathJax.

Comment: Your demo page linked to your original message still has the onload="Print()" on the BODY tag.  And I don't see the MathJax.Hub.Queue() call.  Are you testing on a different page?  Also, I'm not sure why you use javascripts/mathjax.js rather than just loading javascripts/MathJax/MathJax.js directly.  You will need to add the MathJax.Hub.Queue() call to this routine in order to make sure MathJax will be available when the call is made.

Comment: @Davide I have resolved temporarily removing all the messaging. Demo [here](http://stackprinter.appspot.com/export?question=3405&format=HTML&service=math.stackexchange&linktohome=false)

Comment: OK.  Your earlier version (at 1e) still had the mathjax.js file for loading MathJax, and that only SET UP the load, and that script completed before MathJax was actually loaded, and so the next script for the Queue() call failed because MathJax was not yet defined.  your correct version fixes that by properly loading MathJax.js inline.  (You need to remove MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload(), however, since that is only for loading MathJax after the page is loaded.)

Comment: @Davide thanks for your help and greetings for MathJax, impressive work.

Answer (score 2):

The MathJax message area has a delay before it is removed so that you can actually read it.  The `Print()` call apparently blocks the javascript that would have removed the message.  So you need to add a delay of your own before running `Print()`.  I think the message delay is 600 ms, so if you change your

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(Print);
```

call to

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(
  ["Delay",MathJax.Callback,700],
  Print
);
```

then that should delay your `Print()` call until after the message is removed.

Davide

Comment: Don't forget to remove the `MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();` call from your script tag that loads MathJax.  This only for when you insert MathJax into a page *after* it is loaded, not when you load it in the standard way through a script tag in the document head.